# WPF IObservable<T> как источник данных для ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, интерфейс

У меня есть класс, реализующий интерфейс IObservable. В xaml разметке я указал объект этого класса, как источник данных для списка, однако содержимое списка не обновляется.

Вот реализация интерфейса:

```
private List<IObserver<History>> observers = new List<IObserver<History>>();

public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<History> observer)
{
    if (!observers.Contains(observer))
        observers.Add(observer);
    return new Unsubscriber(observers, observer);
}

private class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
{
    private List<IObserver<History>> observers;
    private IObserver<History> observer;

    public Unsubscriber(List<IObserver<History>> observers, IObserver<History> observer)
    {
        this.observers = observers;
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (observer != null && observers.Contains(observer))
            observers.Remove(observer);
    }
}

public void SendChanges()
{
    foreach (IObserver<History> observer in observers)
    {
        observer.OnNext(this);
    }
}
```

Вот классы, которые сигнализируют об обновлении коллекции:

```
public void Add(Action item)
{
    current.Append(item);
    current = item;
    SendChanges();
}

public void Clear()
{
    current = start;
    start.Break();
    SendChanges();
}
```

Comment: 1. Покажите вашу разметку и ваш объект-источник данных. 2. А почему вы считаете, что WPF умеет брать данные из `IObservable` из коробки? Для WPF нужен `INotifyPropertyChanged` и `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: 1. `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding history, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:MainWindow}}}"/>`, `public static History history { get; } = new History();`.
2. А почему нет?

Comment: 2. Потому что это не предусмотрено разработчиками WPF. WPF поддерживает только INPC/INCC и (оставленные для совместимости и не рекомендуемые к использованию) {Name}Changed-события. Ну и Dependency Property ещё.

Comment: @PurpleDragon: А `history` у вас статическое свойство? Нет, к нему так не привяжется. Но даже если бы и привязалось, брать данные из `IObservable` WPF не умеет.

Comment: @PurpleDragon: Почему нет? А потому, что на этапе проектирования было непонятно, как с ним обращаться. Вот приходит новый элемент — что делать со старым? Выкидывать или сохранять? Если `IObservable` — это например последовательные значения переменной величины, то накопление не имеет смысла. Вам придётся накапливать самостоятельно, через `ObserveOnDispatcher` и добавление в `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: По моему, все просто. Из `IObservable` даем сигнал о том, что список изменился и отправляем его. Все получатели выкидывают старый список и обрабатывают новый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `IObservable<T>` реализовал `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Теперь функции изменения коллекции выглядят так:

```
public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

public void Add(Action item)
{
    if (current.next != null) CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, current.next.Tail()));
    CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new List<Action> { item }));

    current.Append(item);
    current = item;
}

public void Clear()
{
    current = start;
    start.Break();

    CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

Теперь все работает.

Comment: Вообще то уже есть "кошерная" и готовая к применению `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: Я в курсе. Но это самый обычный список, который просто сигнализирует об изменении. Мне нужна коллекция, которая будет работать как кнопки вперед/назад по истории в браузере. Т.е. добавляется действие А, добавляется действие Б, добавляется действие В, на этом этапе у нас получается цепочка "А-Б-В", потом сдвигаемся назад, добавляем действие Г, и в итоге у нас выходит цепочка А-Б-Г.